# Compatible Android SDK Error on Nativescript 3.0.3

Tags: android, ios, nativescript

I need help. :(

I was studying Nativescript these past days. And now, I've managed to create an app using the tutorial and I'm currently trying to build it on an Android device to test. When I tried running it using tns run ios, it runs smoothly on an ios emulator. But when I tried running tns run android I got these error.

```
The plugin tns-android@3.0.1 is already installed
TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined
# run android
```

and sometimes..

this..

You need to have Android SDK 22 or later and the latest Android Support Repository installed on your system.

(when I tried to run several solutions like export android sdk, etc...)

I have several Android SDK installed (Please refer to the screenshot below)

[Android SDK Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0R53G.png)

I've validated if my Android SDK url is correct by running:

```
ls $ANDROID_HOME
```

also..

```
ls $ANDROID_HOME/platforms
```

**which shows the ANDROID SDK files.

Lastly, here's my configuration:

```
OS: Mac Sierra Version 10.12.5
NPM: 4.6.1
Node: v6.10.3
Nativescript: 3.0.3
```

What should I do? Please help. :(

Thank you in advance.

Comment: HI, @Lemuel, verify whether the `tns-android` is added in `dependencies` scope in your `package.json` file. If so just remove the following line `"tns-android":"3.0.1"` from the  `dependencies` and rebuild the app again.

Comment: @NikolayTsonev I've actually fixed it by setting the correct $ANDROID_HOME url. :) But thank you :)